# Capture stdout output of a function call

Tags: go, io

Are there any major flaws to implement this test helper function?

I know that the preferred way (refactoring) would simply make the function to be tested *return* its value and delegate printing to another part, but sometimes one has to test what is there.

```golang
import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

// captureStdout calls a function f and returns its stdout side-effect as string
func captureStdout(f func()) string {
    // return to original state afterwards
    // note: defer evaluates (and saves) function ARGUMENT values at definition
    // time, so the original value of os.Stdout is preserved before it is changed
    // further into this function.
    defer func(orig *os.File) {
        os.Stdout = orig
    }(os.Stdout)

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w
    f()
    w.Close()
    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)

    return string(out)
}
```

---

#### Motivational full example

##### main.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

##### main_test.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func Test_main(t *testing.T) {
    want := "Hello, World!\n"
    got := captureStdout(main)
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("main() = %v, want %v", got, want)
    }
}

// captureStdout calls a function f and returns its stdout side-effect as string
func captureStdout(f func()) string {
    // return to original state afterwards
    // note: defer evaluates (and saves) function ARGUMENT values at definition
    // time, so the original value of os.Stdout is preserved before it is
    // changed further into this function.
    defer func(orig *os.File) {
        os.Stdout = orig
    }(os.Stdout)

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w
    f()
    w.Close()
    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)

    return string(out)
}
```

Comment: There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string) on Stack Overflow addressing this problem, with some good solutions to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go `testing` package and tools have built-in facilities for this:

From the documentation of [`testing`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Examples):

> The package also runs and verifies example code. Example functions may include a concluding line comment that begins with "Output:" and is compared with the standard output of the function when the tests are run. (The comparison ignores leading and trailing space.) These are examples of an example:
>
> ```
> func ExampleHello() {
>     fmt.Println("hello")
>     // Output: hello
> }
> ```

This works suitably for testing output against a static, known result of printable text, like in your example.

Comment: Oh wow, this is even better than any review feedback I could have gotten! [testing/run_example.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/testing/run_example.go) contains a standard library maintained version of my needs. Just the output specification as a comment is a bit quirky, but very fine for my testing use case.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
> ```

Why are we ignoring the error return?
Do we really believe there's no way for Pipe to fail?
Even after a bunch of open()'s with no close()?

---

> ```
>     out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)
> ```

This is even more puzzling.
Read errors can never happen?

---

Sorry, I cannot recommend shipping this code in its current state.